# Compare plugin in notepad++ is too bright. Any fix?

Tags: notepad++

Anyway to choose a better color scheme for the notepad++ compare feature?

I can't read any of it!!

I tried to report the bug on sourceforge but couldn't figure out how to make a new ticket and gave up.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of the Compare plugin (and possibly older versions, but I haven't checked) allows you to configure the background colors under **Plugins** → **Compare** → **Settings**.

[image: Screenshot of the Compare Plugin Settings window]

Comment: That was so helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I just edited the color setting of Compare plugin manually, and found the setting is stored in `ComparePlugin.ini` at `%APPDATA%/Notepad++/plugins/config`.

My own color setting is below (for vim Dark Blue style):

```
[Colors]
Added=32768
Removed=8388608
Changed=8388736
Moved=16744448
Highlight=65535
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings** => **Style Configurator** and play around with : **Select Theme** or **Global Styles**.

Hope that will help you. Good luck.